# Not receive php file in gitclone

Tags: php, github, debugging, xampp, git-clone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbHC2.jpg)
I got an error when I used git clone to htdocs file (xampp) and when I opened the project the .php didn't recognize it.

I also checked the setting.json "php.validate.executablePath" everything is ok.

Comment: Have you run `composer install` or `composer update`?

Comment: yes, I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: This is not a good issue. This is related to vscode, ignore it. Check that your code is running in browser or not

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.